Git P4 - git p4 remote and p4 disagree on some files
I have a project using Perforce, and I've grown tired of struggling with it, so I have a local git repository overlaying my P4 workspace that I track changes in. However, at some point two binaries were submitted to P4 and somehow git-p4 failed to pick them up properly, and now my git commit history and P4 changelist history don't agree on those files. git p4 rebase will succeed, but the files will then show up as modified in perforce, and then reverting the files in P4 will make them show up as modified in git, even though git p4 insists that it's up to date. Now, every time I want to run git p4 submit, I first have to go into P4, revert those two files, run the submit, and then git reset --hard p4/master every time. This is frustrating, but I don't know how to force my git repo back into sync with perforce without either re-cloning the whole thing or committing what git thinks the files are and possibly corrupting them somehow.
What is the best way to solve this?

Can you not simply get into the state where the files show as modified by Git, and then commit them in this state to the Git repository?

I don't think so, I have tried but then git p4 submit will fail because of the inconsistency. I don't know of a way to update git without also updating P4.

I don't know what git p4 submit does. You can use git add and git commit to just update Git but not P4.

I understand that, this question is specifically about using git p4.
